# Error: "Unable to Open Database" using sqite3 and Windows

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, sqlite

I'm a newbie to this, and can't figure out how to solve this error that I get when attempting to query from the database. The error reads:

```
rm: cannot unlink 'C:/Users/myName/Documents/GitHub/active_record_lite/lib../cats.db': Permission denied
Error: unable to open database "'C:\Users\myName\Documents\GitHub\active_record_lite'": unable to open database file
```

By going to "Properties" and viewing the "Security" tab, everything is checked under "Allow" for security, so I assume that the project and all subfiles have full permission (is this correct?).

I have a "cats.db" and "cats.sql" file in the project folder.

This is where I attempt to query from the database:

```
require_relative 'db_connection'
require 'active_support/inflector'

class SQLObject
  def self.columns
    cols = DBConnection.execute2(<<-SQL, @table_name)
      SELECT
        *
      FROM
        ?
    SQL
```

And here is a db_connection.rb file:

```
require 'sqlite3'

# https://tomafro.net/2010/01/tip-relative-paths-with-file-expand-path
ROOT_FOLDER = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..')
CATS_SQL_FILE = File.join(ROOT_FOLDER, 'cats.sql')
CATS_DB_FILE = File.join(ROOT_FOLDER, 'cats.db')

class DBConnection
  def self.open(db_file_name)
    @db = SQLite3::Database.new(db_file_name)
    @db.results_as_hash = true
    @db.type_translation = true

    @db
  end

  def self.reset
    commands = [
      "rm '#{CATS_DB_FILE}'",
      "cat '#{CATS_SQL_FILE}' | sqlite3 '#{CATS_DB_FILE}'"
    ]

    commands.each { |command| `#{command}` }
    DBConnection.open(CATS_DB_FILE)
  end

  def self.instance
    reset if @db.nil?

    @db
  end

  def self.execute(*args)
    puts args[0]

    instance.execute(*args)
  end

  def self.execute2(*args)
    puts args[0]

    instance.execute2(*args)
  end

  def self.last_insert_row_id
    instance.last_insert_row_id
  end

  private

  def initialize(db_file_name)
  end
end
```

Any advice/suggestions welcomed! Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you have read and write permissions to both the database itself and the directory that it's in.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, thanks for the response...I believe that I have full access to the directory (accessing "Security" tab through the "Properties"). How would you access the r/w permissions to the database?